# Content Security Policy for Google Fonts/Icons

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, content-security-policy, taco

I am having trouble whitelisting Google's material design icons to show up in a Visual Studio Cordova application (I'm targeting Android 4.x only).

The JS and CSS seem to work fine, but the icons don't show.  When the CSP is commented out, they work. I thought that whitelisting the ***.googleapis.com** would do the trick, but apparently not.

My **Index.html**, which is based on the default Cordova JS Application, with my modified headers is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://fonts.googleapis.com https://*.jquery.com https://*.cloudflare.com https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
                   style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://*.cloudflare.com 'unsafe-inline';
                   media-src *">
    <title>Test CSP</title>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Zen references -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">CSP Test</a>
            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="about" href="#!"><i class="material-icons right">info</i></a></li>
                <li><a class="settings" href="#!"><i class="material-icons right">settings</i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                <li><a class="about" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="settings" href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
            <a class="btn-floating btn-large red" href="#">
                <i class="large material-icons">add</i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My **Config.Xml**, which is the default config, is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myapp740f79" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US">
  <name>BlankCordovaApp1</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />

  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>

  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>

  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>

  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>

  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>

  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="62" height="62" />
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="173" height="173" />
  </platform>

  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
  </platform>

  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
  </platform>

  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920"/>
  </platform>

  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="480" height="800"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: whitelist is version dependent. And filter domains is not straight forward. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) Use the [whitelist matrix](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md) (or worksheet, if you like) - ALSO, if you ever work on iOS, there are major differences.

Comment: Good info, but I'm still stuck on what CATEGORY the google fonts are. I've tried adding `font-src https://*.googleapis.com;` but that doesn't seem to do anything. Still looking...

Comment: Have you tried the **DANGEROUS, BUT WORKING** code?

Comment: I just tried it and  it totally didn't allow anything: `    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" >
` resulted in no execution of the JS, sytles, etc.  I'm using the RIPPLE emulator, but when I've tried it on my device I've had similar results as the emulator so I trust it for the most part.  When the CSP is commented out, everything works fine in debug.

Comment: you may have noticed  I did not post this as an answer. There were many warning signs you were mostly looking for a short-cut. 1. You did not state what your target platform; Android, iOS, etc. 2. You are pulling libraries down from the Internet. Assets should be local; on the device. 3. You did not post your `config.xml` and the remainder of your `index.html`. --- If you add those to your post, or add a link to your code on github.com or pastebin.com, I'll take a look at it. In short, the code you have and your responses lead me to believe you have many, many errors.

Comment: you need to reply when you've made the change, else I cannot see it. Lucky for you I still had this page open, and accidentally recycled it.  SORRY, what is your target. Please add to your post, and reply - so I can see. TIA Jesse

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on SO. I'm targeting Android 4.x (but that is only because it's the default setting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@U1199880,
I'm going to assume this is your first or close to your first app.
You will need to learn how to use parameters. You should play with the example you got from Cordova a bit before you try anything real.

Here are you mistakes and corrections:

1) You should get all your assets local, do not get them from the web. While this may work sometimes, if you do this, your app will behave unpredictably.

Your new header should look like this

```
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width />

<!-- YOUR CODE WILL NOW LOAD ANYTHING. INCLUDING TROJAN CODE -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
          content="default-src *; 
                   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">

<!-- THESE js AND css FILES SHOULD LIVE LOCALLY -->
<!-- Zen references -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
```

Since you are only doing this for Android. I got rid of the garbage.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" 
    id="io.cordova.myapp740f79" 
    version="1.0.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    defaultlocale="en-US">
  <name>App1</name>
  <description>A blank project </description>
  <author href="ME" 
      email="dev@example.org">Me Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />


<!-- YOUR CODE WILL NOW LOAD ANYTHING. INCLUDING TROJAN CODE -->
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <access origin="*" />

  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
  </platform>

</widget>
```

Comment: Not my first app, but it is the first one that that is using CSP, VS, and the latest Cordova CLI 5.x. I understand (and accept) that the assets being local is a "Best Practice".  I'm still in the dark about why white-listing JQuery and Materialize worked, but doing the GoogleApis didn't.

Comment: Sure. This first document explains how to get the whitelist working. I applied it to your app. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) -- This worksheet explains more of the whys, [Whitelist Worksheet (Matrix)](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md). I'm still working on other parts of the document. If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Best of Luck